# android location app that calls an activity at a point of interest

Tags: android, android-activity, location, android-location, point-of-interest

We are working on an android app project that invokes an Activity **directly** at different point of interest (we know its not advicable), **even when the app is not running**. We've done something but the specified Activity is not invoked at the specified POI.  any help..this is the code for two POIs.

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LocationManager lm;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);




        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, new Intent (this, SecondActivity.class),0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, new Intent (this, ThirdActivity.class),0);


         lm.addProximityAlert(3.867247, 11.496267, 20, -1, pendingIntent1); 
        lm.addProximityAlert(3.8626208, 11.495961, 20, -1, pendingIntent2);  
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you post output of your logcat?

Comment: ok thanks for answering @ACengiz here's just part of the logcat..hope it helps you to help me :) '02-05 13:16:58.673: I/ProgramMonitor(3640): cpu_usage_wan
02-05 13:16:59.306: I/StatusBarPolicy(1561): BAT. S:2 H:2
'

Comment: Logcat output is not enough for me to comment about problem. There is not error messages here.

Comment: ok @ACengiz ..this is part of what i got for error logcat '02-05 17:45:42.388: E/GlsClient-query(1568):  at com.google.common.async.AsyncHttpRequestFactory.run(Unknown Source)
02-05 17:45:42.388: E/GlsClient-query(1568):  at com.google.common.lang.BaseThreadFactory$ThreadImpl.run(Unknown Source)
02-05 17:45:42.638: E/PlayEventLogger(2437): Upload failed class java.net.UnknownHostException(play.googleapis.com)
02-05 17:45:44.044: E/SensorManager(2186): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.twtdigital.zoemob.api.dataAcquirer.a@4076dca8
'

Comment: Hi Alain I'm sorry for my late reply but I haven't found a specific answer yet. The reason may be your applications permissions  in your manifest file or a problem about unregistering sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register for location updates before you add proximity alert:

`lm.requestLocationUpdates(...)`

Also make sure you have enabled the location permission on you `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```